# Adding a column to certain row in a data frame pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which contains ids and emails. I also have a dictionary, which contain as a key the id and as a value a phone number. I want to iter on the dictionary and if the id is present in the dictionary then create a new column in the dataframe and add the phone number. I figured out how to see if the id was present in the dictionary but not how to create a new column:

```
for wid in mapping_id_phone:
   print any(id==wid)
```

Comment: Sorry are you after `df['new_col'] = df['my_warner_id'].map(mapping_id_phone)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new'] = df.id.map(mapping_id_phone)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3]})
mapping_id_phone = {1: '123', 2:'456', 3:'789'}
print (df)
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3

df['new'] = df.id.map(mapping_id_phone)
print (df)
   id  new
0   1  123
1   2  456
2   3  789
```

If some value in `dict` is missing, you get `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3, 4]})
mapping_id_phone = {1: '123', 2:'456', 3:'789'}
print (df)
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4

df['new'] = df.id.map(mapping_id_phone)
print (df)
   id  new
0   1  123
1   2  456
2   3  789
3   4  NaN
```